# The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, owin

I have set up a new asp.net web forms application. I want to create a log on and register feature using the provided owin authentication using my own entity framework data model.

I have changed my connection string from the default and within IdentityModels.cs but when using the login I receive the error above.

The code is unchanged from the default and when I change the ApplicationDBContext back to the DefaultConnection it works as expected.

I am able to access data from my database as I have used a linq query to check the email and password entered.

The error is thrown on the following line within the login user control:

```
 var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);
```

Is there something I need to do to make owin authentication work with a database other than the DefaultConnection supplied?

**Code Snippets:**

*Generated Register:*

```
protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text };
            IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {    
                signInManager.SignIn( user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else 
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

*Generated Login:*

```
protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {
                // Validate the user password
                var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

                var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);

                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}", 
                                                        Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                                                        RememberMe.Checked),
                                          true);
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
                        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                        break;
                }
```

*Linq query to find user:*

```
var myUser = db.Dat_Account
                    .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == Email.Text
                    && u.Password == Password.Text);
```

*Generated ApplicationUser*

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
        }
    }
```

My user table has many more fields than just username, email and password. Is it possible that this causes an issue?

*Context:*

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyDBEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you might want to check this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852194/mvc-5-usermanager-the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did look at this article earlier but am unsure how this code would work as the user is passing in username data to an empty constructor. This users code is quite different to the code generated for me by visual studio and I was unable to find a way around my problem. I'll add some of the code to this post.

Comment: Can you show the code for your context as well?

Comment: No Problem, just posted.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Thanks for that, I have removed the C# tag from the post

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have a database initializer so the default behavior would be CreateDatabaseIfNotExists. So either remove the existing database and let EF create it with the identity stuff, or switch the initializer to DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges in your constructor:

```
static ApplicationDbContext() {
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>());
}
```

Once you are up and running and have data you don't want to lose, you should switch the initializer off (Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer());) or use migrations.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm